# Custom Role Authorization by Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm building ASP.NET MVC apps, the apps will check user roles again & again to decide which to display which not.

I have tried WebViewPage to create custom htmlhelper.

```
<p>@Check.isInRole("Admin")</p>
```

Then using private string to store the user's Role

```
private string _Roles { get; set; }
```

but then the _Roles are global and share across all users.

Is there a way I can query DB only once when user connect to webapp for first time, then load all user's roles into Session variable ?

Or

Other workaround method also means a lot to me. Please help.

*****I knew we can use ASP NET Membership, do not want to use for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it, if you have better answer, please do let me know.

with the custom HTML Helper, not it can show view/action link base on User Role

```
@if(tech.isInRole("Admin,Developer"))
{
   //It will show the link only if the user have the above roles
   @Html.ActionLink(......);
}
```

below is the code for custom HTML Helper

```
public abstract class tech : WebViewPage
{
    public static bool isInRole(string roles) {
        string ID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        //This if to skip query Db, if user are in the same session
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["roles"] == null)
        {
            var db = new UserDbContext();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["roles"] = db.UserRoles
                    .Where(a => a.User.Username == ID)
                    .Select(a => a.Role.Rolename).ToArray();
        }

        string[] arrRole = (string[])(HttpContext.Current.Session["roles"]);

        char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
        string[] inRoles = roles.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return arrRole.Intersect(inRoles, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can session. Because it will be shared throughout the app until the session is out.
1st in controller, on logging in, save the role of user in the session variable

```
Session["UserRole"] = user role
```

2nd in view you can get the value

```
@Session["UserRole"].toString()
```

hope this helps

Comment: add where i should put this code Session["UserRole"] = user role, so it only assign once per session ?

Comment: it should in the function which handles ur user authentication for the 1st time. if u assign another value for the same variable then the previous value will be overrided